IllegalStateException: VIEW_MODEL_KEY must always be provided by ViewModelProvider
I'm getting the error below. Does someone know how to fix it?
Below is the logcat and what I did before the error happened.

I run the Gradle update on my project (now is gradle 8.4.1)
Updated multiple libraries versions (including ViewModel lib - now is 2.8.0)
Updated libs from kapt to ksp

I use Koin for injection.
class LoginRegisterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentLoginRegisterBinding
    private val viewModel: LoginRegisterViewModel by viewModel {
        parametersOf(
            AuthClient(),
            FireStoreClient()
        )
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = FragmentLoginRegisterBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setLoginFunction()
        setRegisterUserFunction()
        setForgotPasswordFunction()
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        if (AuthClient.auth.currentUser != null) {
            reload()
        }
    }
}


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: VIEW_MODEL_KEY must always be provided by ViewModelProvider
     at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:83)
     at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$Factory.create(ViewModelProvider.android.kt:158)
     at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ViewModelProviderImpl.getViewModel$lifecycle_viewmodel_release(ViewModelProviderImpl.kt:69)
     at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ViewModelProviderImpl.getViewModel$lifecycle_viewmodel_release$default(ViewModelProviderImpl.kt:47)
     at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.android.kt:91)
     at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.android.kt:109)
     at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.ViewModelResolverKt.resolveInstance(ViewModelResolver.kt:15)
     at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.scope.ScopeExtKt.getViewModel(ScopeExt.kt:67)
     at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.scope.ScopeExtKt.getViewModel(ScopeExt.kt:53)
     at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.scope.ScopeExtKt.getViewModel$default(ScopeExt.kt:45)
     at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.ext.android.ComponentCallbackExtKt.getViewModel(ComponentCallbackExt.kt:63)
     at xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.views.login_register.LoginRegisterActivity$special$$inlined$viewModel$default$2.invoke(ComponentCallbackExt.kt:65)
     at xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.views.login_register.LoginRegisterActivity$special$$inlined$viewModel$default$2.invoke(ComponentCallbackExt.kt:42)
     at kotlin.UnsafeLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:81)
     at xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.views.login_register.LoginRegisterActivity.getViewModel(LoginRegisterActivity.kt:23)
     at xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.views.login_register.LoginRegisterActivity.setLoginFunction(LoginRegisterActivity.kt:48)
     at xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.views.login_register.LoginRegisterActivity.onCreate(LoginRegisterActivity.kt:35)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8975)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8944)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4146)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4322) 
     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) 
     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2685) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103) 


Did you find any solution same error to me when I enabled proguard

@manivannaperumal I solved this by downgrading this lib to version 4.3.8 (Error occurred with version 4.3.10)
classpath "com.google.gms:google-services

I updated today to version 4.4.2, and it's working as well, so it might be something with  the 4.3.10 version

for me im not having gms, just enabled R8 and got this error

I'm facing with this problem after I changed viewmodel's dependencies (I added another database implemeneted by SqlDelight) I created related Module class and Provides, so Hilt has everything.
